# How to specify the content of a new buffer from command line?

Tags: terminal, invocation

Is there a way to call Vim in such a way that it opens a buffer with some content specified on the terminal, i.e. not saved in a file?

For example, I would like to run `vim` and have it open a buffer with `foo, bar, baz and qux` written on it.

Is there an option that does this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
$ echo "foo, bar, baz, and qux" | vim -
```

Or like that?

```
$ vim -c "put='foo, bar, baz, and qux'"
```

Comment: Aww, sweet! I Tried `vim < echo "test"` but with no success. I did not know about `vim -`! And `+`/`-c` can be useful too. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is totally inspired from romainl's one *(many thanks to him)* but it allows to open multiple buffers with multiple strings.

Add the following lines to your `.zshrc` (or `.bashrc` or any relevant file where you define your bash functions)

```
function mvim {
    CMD="vim "
    for string in "$@"
    do
        CMD=$CMD"-c \"enew | put='"$string"'\" "
    done
    CMD=$CMD"-c \"bufdo 1d\""

    eval $CMD
}
```

After sourcing your `.zshrc` file you'll be able to call the following function:

```
mvim "foo bar" "baz" "and quz"
```

Which will open a vim instance with 3 buffers, each one containing one string.

If no argument is provided a regular vim instance will be started. If one argument is an empty string, an empty buffer will be created.

**EDIT** I realized that for a reason that I don't understand an empty line is created at the beginning of each buffer so I added the line

```
CMD=$CMD"-c \"bufdo 1d\""
```

To get rid of this empty line in all buffers.

Comment: That is an interesting script. Might be useful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

I've recently looked for a way, how to put the clipboard content into a new buffer in vim. I think, it is worth to share it here:

```
vim -c "put! *"
```

**UPDATE:**
This will `put` the text from register `*` before `!` the current line.

The `*` and `+` registers refers to clipboard in windows.

On linux `+` has the content of the clipboard and `*` contains the selected text.

Comment: In the vimrc that could even be done automatically if argc is 0.

Comment: Maybe you could refer `:help quotestar` and `:help quoteplus` in your answer to help those who don't know those registers understand why this command works. Also on GNU/Linux there is a difference between `*` and `+`, while on Windows they are equivalent.